# TCP: Какому именно буферу задают размер ReceiveBufferSize и SendBufferSize, нужно ли их изменять в каком-то случае?

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, tcp-ip, сокеты

Например, в C# есть `TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` и `TcpClient.SendBufferSize` (по сути они основаны на системной функции setsockopt).

Хочу понять, на что они влияют, размер ***какого именно*** буфера они задают, ведь в ядре ОС и библиотеке WinSock явно не один буфер есть :)

Посмотрел, какие у них значения по умолчанию.
В Windows 8 (x64) они по умолчанию равны 65536.
В Windows Server 2003 (x64) - 8192.

Ситуация #1.
Попробовал создать сервер и клиент, работающие по такому алгоритму:
- клиент подключается к серверу
- сервер (Win2003) одним вызовом Write передает клиенту файл в 70000 байт (размер выбрал больше обоих буферов)
- клиент (Win8) ждет несколько секунд и только потом я ***вручную*** вызываю Read на клиенте, опять же пытаюсь считать 70000 байт одним вызовом Read
- при этом сетевое подключение стабильное
Результат: файл передается нормально read возвращает 70000 байт и действительно файл не поврежден. Значит, в этом случае размер буферов не влияет.

Ситуация #2.
А что будет при обрыве кабеля, который потом устранится и накопленные (в буфере?) байты должны отправиться приемнику и считаться? В этом случае не повлияет ли размер буфера?
То есть такой алгоритм:
- клиент подключился к серверу
- произошел обрыв кабеля
- а в это время клиент быстро сформировал массив в 70000 байт, вызвал Write, массив добавился в очередь (в какой-то ***буфер***)
- и тут кабель быстро вернули на место, все произошло очень быстро, так что клиент и сервер не успели вылететь из-за "неподключенных сокетов", так что сервер начинает получать эти байты в сегментах и читать их
Но ведь их 70000, может таких Write даже N раз подряд было до того как кабель вернулся на место, а лимит буферов по умолчанию всего лишь 8192 и 65536, в любом случае меньше, чем 70000 и тем более 70000*N.

Вторую ситуацию я пока не моделировал, только собираюсь.

Насколько вам известно: что произойдет? Не будет ли потери накопленных данных в этом случае, не окажутся ли они в "черной дыре"?

И главный вопрос: стоит ли изменять размер этих буферов в расчете на очень нестабильное подключение? Или их не надо трогать без нужды?
Для чего вообще сделана возможность их трогать?
Производительность не столь важна, гигабайтов я передавать не планирую, и задержки даже в несколько секунд не страшны.

UPD: А вот еще в MSDN у WinSock в списке есть такая ошибка:

> WSAENOBUFS 10055 No buffer space available. An operation on a socket
>   could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer
>   space or because a queue was full.

Это в каких случаях бывает? И тот ли это буфер, размер которого задают те параметры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего уточню, что я работаю с Unix, поэтому по вызовам и свойствам в Win не смогу много уточнить.

> Какому именно буферу задают размер ReceiveBufferSize и SendBufferSize

Задают размер буферам приема и отправки сокета клиента или сервера, в зависимости от того, к чему применяете свойства. (setsockopt(), аналогично, задает свойства некоторого передаваемого ей в параметрах сокета). Эти буферы хранят данные, пока они не будут считаны приложением.

> стоит ли изменять размер этих буферов в расчете на очень нестабильное подключение? Или их не надо трогать без нужды?
> Для чего вообще сделана возможность их трогать?

Ну к примеру, Вы знаете: Ваш сервер всегда шлет клиенту пакет данных, размер которого всегда более 10 Кб. Хотелось бы, чтобы клиент всегда получал этот пакет целиком, и приступал к обработке, а не висел в ожидании в read(). Или же другой пример: Вы точно знаете, что вот сейчас вычислится пачка данных в 10 Кб на сервере, и вы хотите максимально быстро отправить ее клиенту. Если буфер отправки сокета на сервере будет всего 4 Кб, то отправить всю пачку сразу не получится, и сервер будет ожидать в write(), пока клиент не начнет читать эти данные, и место в буфере не освободится.
Таким образом, это возможность оптимизировать производительность передачи данных. При небольших размерах буферов сокетов, производительность может быть меньше ожидаемой (канал с высокой пропускной способностью не будет заполнен). Большие размеры буферов требуются в каналах с высокой пропускной способностью.

> Не будет ли потери накопленных данных в этом случае, не окажутся ли они в "черной дыре"?

Если все, что Вы описываете в ситуации 2 произошло "настолько быстро", то потери данных быть не должно - об этом должен заботиться TCP, на то и надежный протокол. Возможно, что при активном обмене данными между клиентом и сервером система не разделит Ваше мнение о "настолько быстром устранении обрыва", в этом случае вызовы read() или write() вернут ошибку или количество записанных/считанных байт меньше ожидаемого, - этот случай естественно необходимо обрабатывать.

> Но ведь их 70000, может таких Write даже N раз подряд было до того как кабель вернулся на место

write(), как и read(), блокирующий системный вызов, и он будет пытаться записать все данные, если не возникло критической ошибки или сокет не был помечен как неблокируемый. Если запись по каким-то причинам не удалась, write вернет ошибку или значение количества байт, которое ему удалось записать, лишнего в никуда писать не станет.

> WSAENOBUFS 10055 No buffer space available. An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
>
> Это в каких случаях бывает? И тот ли это буфер, размер которого задают те параметры?

Да, буфер именно тот. Это может возникнуть, например, на стороне сервера, если клиент медленно считывает данные, а сервер шлет их слишком быстро, и его буфер отправки сокета переполнился. Возможно, то же самое сообщение будет, если приемный буфер сокета клиента меньше, чем буфер отправки сокета на сервере, а сервер пишет туда единовременно больше данных, чем допускает размер буфера отправки сокета.